# parse apache tomcat serverl.xml in bash

Tags: xml, bash, parsing

I want to parse the value pattern from servers.xml using linux command.

condition

1. the variable pattern must be valid meaning it should not be inside comments

   ```
   <!--- comments  -->
   ```
2. if the variable is inside comments,parser should not return anything.

PFB the xml

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
pattern="%h %t %m %U %q %s %b %D %{X-Forwarded-For}i " />
```

Comment: This is unclear question...

Comment: Why don'y use python for parsing xml files?

Comment: mortezaL:: can u help me in python for the above task..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
cat server.xml | sed '/<!--.*-->/d'| sed '/<!--/,/-->/d' | awk '/pattern/ {print $2}' FS='"'
```

First, we remove the comments, then we look for the value of `pattern`.

Answer (score 0):

Folks.

Please try this

This worked for me

```
xmlstarlet el -v server.xml | grep -w @pattern  | awk -F'=' '{print $(NF)}'  | sed 's/]//g
```